# XNA Keys number 1

Tags: xna, key

I need to ask when the number 1 key is pressed, NOT on the Numpad, but the number 1 that is over the Q (trying to make this as clear as possible).

I've been through all the available keys on the Keys array, but no one matches the one that I am looking for.

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

My code:

```
If (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.1))
```

Answer (score 10):

Should be the Keys.D1 key. The number keys are D0-D9. The documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keys.aspx).

The documentation says: Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I got confused with the description on the documentation when I read it, so I didn't try that one before.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify: Keys.D1 works (e.g. Keys.D[insert number here]).

```
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D4))
{
Console.WriteLine("You pressed the 4 key above E and R!");
}
```